# Django with Docker Module NOT found Error

Tags: python, django, docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

I am trying to build a Django app with Docker. My application will run on local server however when I try to migrate with docker it throws a Module Not Found Error. This is my requirements.txt

```
djangorestframework==3.7.0
Django==1.11.5
#import_export==0.5.1
django-csvimport==2.2
psycopg2
```

This is my docker-compose.yml`.

```
docker-compose.yml

version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python djangorest/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
#COPY . /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

I am get following error when i pass this cmd docker-compose run web python djangorest/manage.py migrate

```
docker-compose run web python djangorest/manage.py migrate


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "djangorest/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 120, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'csvimport'
```

This is my settings.py file

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'api',
    'csvimport.app.CSVImportConf',
    'import_export',

]
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code or maybe I miss something here.

Comment: Did you find solution ? I have same issue with `import_export`...